# How do I get Dark Mode on Apple's Numbers

Tags: numbers, accessibility

How do you get Numbers to be in Dark Mode. (The OS itself is in Dark Mode)

You can change the background of the spreadsheet buy use of Format Text

But how do you get the surrounds to be white on black that is showing the value of the cell at the bottom of the sheet
Seeing the formula in a cell.
The headings giving the number of the row and alphabetical letter of the column.

For example if you choose a new sheet of template Blank Black - How do you get all parts of numbers to be white on black?
[image: Example from new Blank Black]

Comment: Do you mean you want to change column and line title bars to have a dark background? And also the function field (not sure if it's named like that)?

Answer (score -1):

If you have OS Ventura or later, you can change the Numbers menus to dark by changing the entire system to dark mode.

To change to systemwide dark mode, go to System Settings (select the Apple, usually top left), then select the Appearance tab (left menu). From there you can choose the mode: light, dark, or auto.

[Read more about that here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208976)

[image]

[image]

Numbers right now (auto, daytime)

[image]

Numbers right now (dark, daytime)

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have done all that and you end up with the screen shot I showed, Can you provide a screen shot of a blank sheet in Numbers

Comment: I've added some images. Just to be clear, dark mode from the system settings will only change the menus. You still have to select the dark template or set backgrounds to dark (right-click on sheet name => show sheet options -> background).

Comment: Note that if you choose the sheet options the row/column labels are foreground and background black so no letters etc which is of no use. Also click on a cell and the row/column bars conm back but still black foreground on white background.